# MVC to WCF Claims Bearer Token

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, claims-based-identity

We're setting up a new solution which will basically be configured for service oriented architecture as follows:

- MVC Web App - Front end for users
- WCF Service - Service to be used for all data retrieval tasks
- WCF Workflow Service - To be called by the WCF Service

All users will authenticate against our Azure Active Directory tenant.

We need to pass the identity of the user up to the WCF service (and subsequent workflow) calls so that we know who the user is.

Is this possible using the UseWsFederationAuthentication OWIN component with say ws-trust? Everything I seem to read suggests using openId and implementing a custom JWT handler.

In the interest of keeping everything out of the box / standard, we'd like to investigate whether it's possible to achieve this flow using normal SAML / bearer tokens. And if so, could you point us towards a tutorial?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of implementing custom token service or JWT handler, I would suggest you to have a look at IdentityServer (https://identityserver.io/ https://github.com/identityserver). All the heavy lifting is done by the framework and is pretty easy to consume.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've take a look at the IdentityServer and JWT handling. I was wondering if the above flow is possible without JWT tokens? Rather, using normal ws-federation/saml tokens? Or are they just dealing with the identity of the consuming app rather than the actual logged in user?

Comment: May be I'll explain a bit on what I did in my project. Our project had users managed internally (username & password in app database) and users which are managed by different IdP's, for eg, one of them was ADFS. So for the ADFS users, when they select their provider from App login page (just like login via facebook/twitter etc), they will be redirected to their ADFS login page and on authenticating, their IdP will post the SAML token to our configured end point. After validation, we will internally create a JWT/ref token (done by Identity server) so that IdSrv middlewares with manage the rest.

Comment: Have a look at this article - https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Identity-Server-3-using-WS-Federation . May be you are interested in the second type mentioned there.